# split two words using comma in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to separate two words using ',' and save it in different id's.

```
def create  
  @categories = Category.new(:category => params[:category].split(','))     
  @category.save
  redirect_to products_url
end
```

In this case it doesn't work, it will save in the same id. what I have to do to save two words in different ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
params[:category].split(',').each do |category|
    Category.create(category: category)
end
```

Try this code.

Answer (score 1):

Since `split` returns an array of splitted strings, you need to loop over them and save each in a separate `Category`:

```
params[:category].split(',').each do |cat|
  Category.create!(category: cat)
end

redirect_to products_url
```

Answer (score 0):

You need iterate each category

```
params[:category].split(',').each do |category|
    Category.create(category: category)
end
```